How long do powers copied by Mimic power persist?
There is a power called Mimic on Page 169 of Deluxe Hero Handbook that reads as such.

You can duplicate the traits of another character you can
perceive, requiring a move action to scan them. You gain
(Mimic rank x 5) power points worth of traits the target
has, up to a maximum of the target’s rank, and limited
by the total power points you can Mimic. If you can only
mimic some traits, apply the Limited flaw to this power.

But the trait does not appear to mention a duration. Would a character using the mimic archetype on Page 41 be able to copy every power they come across or is there a limit to it like a scene or a limit to how many powers they can copy?

You keep them as long as you maintain them. Variable, and therefore Mimic, is of a Sustained duration. Nothing in the description indicates that your knowledge of the power exceeds the current scene. A GM can choose to enforce whatever mechanics they and their player agree upon if they feel that there needs to be more elaborate mechanics.
